# Check if specified user belongs to specific group or not

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-security

I posted this question on SharePoint exchange but it did not get any attention. Any help will be appreciated.

I have implemented a site and have added a SharePoint group called "`SG_Uploader`".

In this group, I `ONLY` have one Active Directory group called "`AD_L6`" and there are many users in AD_L6.

If a user comes to site and I want to check if he can upload a document, I use below code which is very simple:

```
SPWeb web = // ...
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["SG_Uploader"];
if (group.ContainsCurrentUser)
{
    // allow user to upload
}
```

Now, I want to do the same thing, not for current user but for a specific user that I have his username. By that mean I want to write a code like

```
SPWeb web = // ...
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["SG_Uploader"];
if (group.ContainsUser(username))
{
    // allow user to upload
}
```

I could not figure out who I can do that. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The following code for your reference.

```
var username = "user1";
var spGroupName = "SG_Uploader";
var adGroupName = "AD_L6";
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://sp2013/sites/team/"))
{
    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPUser user = spWeb.EnsureUser(adGroupName);
        if (user.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name.Equals(spGroupName)))
        {

            var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, adGroupName);
            var  isGroupMember = group.Members.Any(x => x.Name == username);
            if (isGroupMember)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User " + username + " is a member of group " + spGroupName);
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User " + username + " is not a member of group "+spGroupName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This also is not the answer however it is helpful. it only works if username is direct member of adGroupName. if not looks like I have to use a recursive function to find if the username is art of adGroupName. I'm not sure if there is any easier way. I'm afraid that resursivly calling AD functions may have a performance problem in my case. +1

Comment: If you check if the user is a member of ad group, we have to use some method to connect the AD.

Comment: Do you know what is that method? does it give me the correct result even if the user is not directly part of a group. in my case (in AD), I have group A which has group B and group B has group C and user is member of group C

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

```
  string userName = "PERSEUS\\dmitry.kaloshin";
        string groupName = "Home Members";
        using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://perseus"))
        {
            using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPUser user = spWeb.EnsureUser(userName);
                if (user.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name.Equals(groupName)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User " + userName + " is a member of group " + groupName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("User " + userName + " is NOT a member of group " + groupName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Visit  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/65066c08-9924-4935-9bba-f715b75d3fac/how-to-check-if-user-exists-in-a-particular-sharepoint-group-or-not-programatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this exact solution but it does not satisfy my requirement.